# XAMPP PHP7.2 - MySQL shutting down unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

This is the File From error logs

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 3316546; transaction id 3975

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

2020-01-25 10:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200125 10:23:54
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you are using the SQL server until the unexpected closure?

Comment: after starting the xamp and clicking on the start button near mysql., it just starts and after 5-6 seconds its getting stopped and showing error